# calculate number and names of similar sounding words from a data frame

Tags: r

I have a data frame that's looks like this

```
    Word<-c("bat", "cat", "cab", "some", "ban", "bait", "at", "done", "dot", "ran", "cant")
    S1<-c("b","c","c","s", "b", "b", "a", "d","d", "r", "c")
    S2<-c("a","a","a","o","a","a","t","o","o","a","a")
    S3<-c("t","t","b","m", "n", "i", "", "n","t", "n", "n")
    S4<-c("","","","e", "", "t", "", "e","", "", "t")
    df<-data.frame(Word, S1, S2, S3, S4,  stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

I want to calculate the number and names of similar sounding words. By similar sounding words I mean words that differ by one sound either by addition, substitution or deletion. In short, I want something like this

```
    Word<-c("bat", "cat", "cab", "some", "ban", "bait", "at", "done", "dot", "ran", "cant")
    S1<-c("b","c","c","s", "b", "b", "a", "d","d", "r", "c")
    S2<-c("a","a","a","o","a","a","t","o","o","a","a")
    S3<-c("t","t","b","m", "n", "i", "", "n","t", "n", "n")
    S4<-c("","","","e", "", "t", "", "e","", "", "t")
    Number<-c(4,4,1,0,2,1,2,0,0,1,2)
    Names<-c("cat, ban, bait, at", "bat, cab, at, cant","cat","","bat, ran","bat","bat, cat","","","ban","can, cat")
    df2<-data.frame(Word, S1, S2, S3, S4, Number, Names,  stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood correctly, it seems like you are looking for [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) between your subject words. The `adist` function in the utils package can calculate the Levenshtein distance for you. It returns a matrix with the number of substutions/insertions/deletions to get from the i-th word to the j-th word.

```
dist <- utils::adist(Word)
dist
```

```
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11]
 [1,]    0    1    2    4    1    1    1    4    2     2     2
 [2,]    1    0    1    4    2    2    1    4    2     2     1
 [3,]    2    1    0    4    2    3    2    4    3     2     2
 [4,]    4    4    4    0    4    4    4    2    3     4     4
 [5,]    1    2    2    4    0    2    2    3    3     1     2
 [6,]    1    2    3    4    2    0    2    4    3     3     2
 [7,]    1    1    2    4    2    2    0    4    2     2     2
 [8,]    4    4    4    2    3    4    4    0    2     3     3
 [9,]    2    2    3    3    3    3    2    2    0     3     3
[10,]    2    2    2    4    1    3    2    3    3     0     2
[11,]    2    1    2    4    2    2    2    3    3     2     0
```

Then, you could loop over the rows or column and return any words with a distance of 1:

```
links <- apply(dist, 1, function(d) {
  paste0(Word[d == 1], collapse = ", ")
})
cbind.data.frame(Word, links)
```

```
   Word              links
1   bat cat, ban, bait, at
2   cat bat, cab, at, cant
3   cab                cat
4  some                   
5   ban           bat, ran
6  bait                bat
7    at           bat, cat
8  done                   
9   dot                   
10  ran                ban
11 cant                cat
```

And now you have derived the first and last column of `df2` programatically. For the counts you can simply use:

```
counts <- apply(dist, 1, function(d){sum(d == 1)})
```

Comment: Yes, I am trying to calculate Levenshtein distance but not for English. I have another  language where Words are like "ban1", "an2", "dang4", "sian3", where I want to calculate Levenshtein distance. When I apply this code, it shows error "dim(X) must have a positive length".

Comment: At what step of the code does it throw this error? Do you have a short vector of characters that throw this error, so I could check?

Comment: Also, if i want to calculate the number and names of similar words using different scheme. For example, for word "ban1" words that differ by "b", "an" or "1" by either addition, deletion or substitution. Thats the reason I have columns like S1, S2, S3,S4 that can help in defining the distance to calculate similar sounding words.

Comment: the error occur when I run this line of code:   links <- apply(dist, 1, function(d) {
  paste0(Word[d == 1], collapse = ", ")
})

Comment: here is the sample of data:  Word<-c("ban1", "an2", "daN4", "sian4", "dan2", "xen3", "yon3") 
S1<-c("b","","d","s", "d", "x", "y")
S2<-c("a","a","a","i","a","e","o")
S3<-c("n","n","N","a", "a", "e", "o")
S4<-c("","","","n", "", "", "")
S5<-c("1","2","4","4", "2", "3", "3")
df<-data.frame(Word, S1, S2, S3, S4, S5,  stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

Comment: another set looks like this: Word<-c("ban1", "an2", "daN4", "sian4", "dan2", "xen3", "yon3") 
S1<-c("b","","d","s", "d", "x", "y")
S2<-c("an","an","aN","ian","an","en","on")
S3<-c("1","2","4","4", "2", "3", "3")
df<-data.frame(Word, S1, S2, S3,  stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

Comment: For me both of your example just run fine without any errors.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I can do it for the first set where words that differ by one sound are similar words.  But in the second set, words that differ by S1 or S2 or S3 by addition, deletion or substitution are similar words. So the distance in not 1 sound but depends in S2 column where the string of sounds is considered as 1unit.