# Calculate number and names of similar sounding words from two different data frames

Tags: r

I have two data frames

```
    Word1<-c("bat", "ban", "bait")
    df1<-data.frame(Word1,  stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

and

```
    Word2<-c("cat", "cab", "ban", "at", "done", "dot", "ran", "cant")
    df2<-data.frame(Word2,  stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

I want to calculate levenshtein distance for words in df1, using the Words in df2

I want something like this:

```
    Word1<-c("bat", "ban", "bait")
    links<-c("cat, ban, at", "ran","")
    counts<-c("3","1","0")
    df3<-data.frame(Word1, links, counts,  stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Its similar to my previous question in calculation but requires two separate data frames. here's the link for the question:

[calculate number and names of similar sounding words from a data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57535840/calculate-number-and-names-of-similar-sounding-words-from-a-data-frame)

Comment: If you are indeed interested in similar sounding words, then you are maybe after `phonetic()` from `stringdist` library.

Answer (score 5):

An option is `agrep`.  Based on the description off `agrep`

> Searches for approximate matches to pattern (the first argument) within each element of the string x (the second argument) using the generalized Levenshtein edit distance (the minimal possibly weighted number of insertions, deletions and substitutions needed to transform one string into another).

We loop through the elements of 'Word1' from 'df1', apply `agrep`, get the corresponding elements of 'df2', 'Word2' column, and create a column of 'counts' by checking the `length`.  Finally, `rbind` the `list` of `data.frame`s to a single one

```
cbind(df1['Word1'], do.call(rbind, lapply(df1$Word1, function(x) {
         i1 <- agrep(x, df2$Word2)
     data.frame(links = toString(df2$Word2[i1]) , counts = length(i1))})))
```

Comment: it works with these words. But on a bigger dataframe where I have word like "on" than the output is "ban, done, dot, ran, cant" which is more than one edit distance from "on".

Comment: @ceba  It is based on levenstein distance that you mentioned in the post

Comment: But for some words this code give 2 edit distance. for example "on" has all 2 edit distance words. "adist" function works well that's mentioned in the link i gave with my problem. But I don't know how to apply that for 2 separate data frames

Comment: @ceba The `adist` takess two arguments, x, y. which are character vectors.  So you can do `adist(df1$Word1, df2$Word2)`